# how can I execute 3 asynchronous functions in order?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
adjust_geo = function(callback){Plasma.Hose('edge-to-sluice').Deposit({
          "descrips": [
            "sluice",
            "prot-spec v1.0",
            "request",
            "zoom"
          ],
          "ingests": {
            "lat": stickie.latitude,
            "lon": stickie.longitude,
            "level": stickie.zoom_level
          }
        });
        Plasma.Hose('edge-to-sluice').Deposit({
          "descrips": [
            "sluice",
            "prot-spec v1.0",
            "request",
            "set-time"
          ],
          "ingests": {
            "time": stickie.start,
            "rate": 2.0,
            "pause": false
          }
        });
        callback();
        }        

         var remove_stickies = function(callback){      
           Plasma.Hose('edge-to-sluice').Deposit({ descrips: ['sluice', 'prot-spec v1.0', 'request', 'remove-all-fluoro'], ingests : {}
        });
        callback();
        }   


        deposit_fluoros = function(){
        console.log(stickie.fluoroscopes);
        L = JSON.parse(stickie.fluoroscopes);
        console.log(L);
        for (var i = 1; i<L.length;i++){
                console.log(L[i]);                
                 Plasma.Hose('tcp://localhost/edge-to-sluice')
                        .Deposit({
                          "descrips": [
                            "sluice", 
                           "prot-spec v1.0",
                            "request",
                            "new-fluoro-instance"], 
                           "ingests":L[i] 
                       }); 
                };
          } 
          }  
     adjust_geo(remove_stickies(deposit_fluoros()));
```

as you can see on the last line, I am attempting to execute the three asnychronous functions in order. However right now it is complaining that callback() on line 34 is undefined. TypeError: undefined is not a function. Its strange because it doesn't seem to care about the one in adjust_geo?

Comment: Promises is the way to go. Avoid callbacks for async functions, it'll confuse you quickly.

Comment: The reason you're getting the error on 34 is because callback() is called outside the remove_stickies function.

Comment: what is the desired order of execution of `adjust_geo`, `remove_stickies` and `deposit_fluoros`?

Comment: @Igor it should be adjust_geo, then remove_stickies, then deposit_fluoros

Comment: @user3727514 - then VitaliyG's response is your answer

Comment: I rolled back your edit as it made all the answers irrelevant, if you are still having problems, ask a new question

Comment: im not sure if it is working. my functions still are executing in the wrong order, yet the console is logging the outputs adjust_geo, remove_stickies, deposit_flouros in the wrong order. Is it possible that the functions themselves are being called in the correct order yet perhaps the callback inside is executing before the main code block (Plasma.Hose, ... ) finishes?

Comment: @user3727514 - it is possible if `Plasma.Hose(...).Deposit` itself is asynchronous. In that case it is very likely has means of accepting a callback to be called on completion - which you should use.

Answer (score 1):

There is problems with your last line (you have to pass callback function and not make function call) and you have pass callback into all functions or check in code if callback was passed:

```
adjust_geo(
  function(){
    remove_stickies(
      deposit_fluoros
    )
  });
```

This will call **adjust_geo** with callback that will call **remove_stickies** with callback that will call **deposit_fluoros** .

If `Plasma.Hose('...').Deposit` looks like `Plasma.Hose('...').Deposit(data, doneCallback)` you can update your code to run functions in order by moving next function calls into `doneCallback`:

```
adjust_geo = function(callback) {
    Plasma.Hose('edge-to-sluice').Deposit({
            "descrips": [
                "sluice",
                "prot-spec v1.0",
                "request",
                "zoom"
            ],
            "ingests": {
                "lat": stickie.latitude,
                "lon": stickie.longitude,
                "level": stickie.zoom_level
            }
        },
        function() {
            Plasma.Hose('edge-to-sluice').Deposit({
                "descrips": [
                    "sluice",
                    "prot-spec v1.0",
                    "request",
                    "set-time"
                ],
                "ingests": {
                    "time": stickie.start,
                    "rate": 2.0,
                    "pause": false
                }
            }, callback)
        }
    );
}

var remove_stickies = function(callback) {
    Plasma.Hose('edge-to-sluice').Deposit({
        descrips: ['sluice', 'prot-spec v1.0', 'request', 'remove-all-fluoro'],
        ingests: {}
    }, callback);
}


deposit_fluoros = function() {
    console.log(stickie.fluoroscopes);
    L = JSON.parse(stickie.fluoroscopes);
    console.log(L);
    for (var i = 1; i < L.length; i++) {
        console.log(L[i]);
        Plasma.Hose('tcp://localhost/edge-to-sluice')
            .Deposit({
                "descrips": [
                    "sluice",
                    "prot-spec v1.0",
                    "request",
                    "new-fluoro-instance"
                ],
                "ingests": L[i]
            });
    };
}
}

adjust_geo(
    function() {
        remove_stickies(
            deposit_fluoros
        )
    });
```

Comment: this makes sense to me and now the console is logging adjust_geo, remove_stickies, deposit_fluoros in the correct order. Yet the functions themselves still appear to be executing in the wrong order. Is it possible that the callbacks inside of the functions are executing before that main code block (Plasma.Hose. ....) finishes?

Comment: Actually all functions in this question are **not** asynchronous. I guess `Plasma.Hose('...').Deposit` is asynchronous, and in this case you have to pass `callback` inside this functions.

Answer (score 0):

Change you last line to read

```
adjust_geo(remove_stickies(deposit_fluoros));
```

The way you are doing it currently doing it, you are passing the RESULT of deposit_fluoros as opposed to passing a reference to the function.

Comment: this will not pass a callback to `adjust_geo`

Answer (score 0):

Removed all other objects, just plain callbacks. Put back your objects and it will work. Key rule whenever you are returning or calling the callback make sure you return it as function.

```
var adjust_geo = function (callback) {

    callback();
    console.log('adjust_geo');
}
// wrap the result of first call into a function and return it
var remove_stickies = function (callback) {
    return function () {
        callback()
        console.log('remove_stickies');
    };
}


var deposit_fluoros = function () {
    console.log('deposit_fluoros')
};

adjust_geo(remove_stickies(deposit_fluoros));
```

Output:

```
"deposit_fluoros"
"remove_stickies"
"adjust_geo"
```

Comment: hmm this doesn't give any undefined errors. but it still seems that it is going in order of remove_stickies, deposit_fluoros, adjust_geo. Maybe I should use promises instead?

Comment: Updated my answer- if you add your code wherever there is console.log statements, it will be in order.

Comment: Promises also rely on callbacks behind the scene, so it's not really one vs. the other. Also No browsers support promises natively in a reliable way